# how to find the elements from an array which are not in another array using golang?

Tags: go

i have two array A and B ,A["anusha","kirthy","reema"],B["anusha","raju","sudha"].i need to get the elements of an array A which are not in array B .result will be ["kirthy","reema"] in golang .please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Playground solving your problem (Quick and Dirty, there may be better solutions out there, but this one works.): https://play.golang.org/p/7vTXLtaGNh

This Problem sounds like a simple homework, with a bit tinkering you could've solved it yourself i guess.